# Neo4j 2.0.0 M3 Initialization Failure

Tags: database, neo4j

I've been using the neo4j 2.0.0 M3 release for the past month or so in developing a simple web application. I've had absolutely no issues with the release until today when I went to start the database.

I'm a bit of a novice and am having a hard time determining what exactly the cause of the problem is and how to go about fixing it. The error log is below, I was hoping to get some help in interpreting the output. Thanks!

```
  Jul 23, 2013 11:10:16 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@b05236' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:319)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:100)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.recovery.StoreRecoverer.recover(StoreRecoverer.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.run(PerformRecoveryIfNecessary.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.server.preflight.PreFlightTasks.run(PreFlightTasks.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.runPreflightTasks(AbstractNeoServer.java:299)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:132)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:86)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:49)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@b05236' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:296)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@6760bf50' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:504)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.start(XaDataSourceManager.java:126)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.doInternalRecovery(XaLogicalLog.java:765)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.open(XaLogicalLog.java:160)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaContainer.openLogicalLog(XaContainer.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:304)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:498)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 21 more
Jul 23, 2013 11:10:16 AM org.neo4j.server.logging.Logger log
SEVERE: Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]
```

Comment: what version of Java are you using. Are you in case running it using Java 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of [System Requirements](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/deployment-requirements.html) for Neo4J. It says you need Java 7.

Looks like you are using Java 6 for which `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel` is thrown. Using Java 7 should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jatin. I probably should have figured this out myself but for whatever reason it had been launching just fine in Java 6 up until today.